# For what values of $a$ does this improper integral converge?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$\text{Let}\;\; I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}{x^{\large\frac{4a}{3}}}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^a}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

I need to find all $a$ such that $I$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** Near $x=0$, $\arctan(x)\sim x$ whereas near $x=+\infty$, $\arctan(x)\sim\pi/2$.

**Hint 2:** Near $x=0$, consider $a\ge0$ and $a\lt0$. Near $x=+\infty$, consider $a\ge\frac12$ and $a\lt\frac12$.

Comment: $\arctan(x)\sim \dfrac{\pi}{2},\;\; x\to {+\infty}$

Comment: @M.Strochyk: The idea is that it is bounded, but thanks for the correction.